# How can I find tizen embeded apps in the devices?

Tags: tizen

For example, I want to find tpk of videoplayer
in tizen devices or emulator.
but I can't find the path, anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

Apps are located in /usr/apps. If you can't find there what you seek, you can try:

```
sdb shell
su
find / | grep video
```

When you run application you can also check process list and then try to grep for it.